# error in getting the correct date using strptime in R

Tags: r, strptime

I'm using `strptime` to extract date and the result is a wrong year 
Where is the error in the below code:

```
strptime('8/29/2013 14:13', "%m/%d/%y") 
[1] "2020-08-29 PDT"
```

What are the other ways to extract date and time as separate columns.
The data I have is in this format - `8/29/2013 14:13`
I want to split this into two columns, one is `8/29/2013` and the other is `14:13`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a four digit year so you need to use %Y

```
strptime('8/29/2013 14:13', "%m/%d/%Y" )
[1] "2013-08-29 CEST"
```

Do you really want data and time in separate columns? It usually much easier to deal with a single date-time object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility to separate time and date from the string.

For convenience, we could first convert the string into a POSIX object:

```
datetime <- '8/29/2013 14:13'
datetime.P <- as.POSIXct(datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

Then we can use `as.Date()` to extract the date from this object and use `format()` to display it in the desired format:

```
format(as.Date(datetime.P),"%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "08/29/2013"
```

To store the time separately we can use, e.g., the `strftime()` function:

```
strftime(datetime.P, '%H:%M')
#[1] "14:13"
```

The last function (`strftime()`) is not vectorized, which means that if we are dealing with a vector `datetime` containing several character strings with date and time in the format as described in the OP, it should be wrapped into a loop like `sapply()` to extract the time from each string.

---

**Example**

```
datetime <- c('8/29/2013 14:13', '9/15/2014 12:03')
datetime.P <- as.POSIXct(datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
format(as.Date(datetime.P),"%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "08/29/2013" "09/15/2014"
sapply(datetime.P, strftime, '%H:%M')
#[1] "14:13" "12:03"
```

---

Hope this helps.